# Turing Machine that accepts $L=\{a^nb^n | n \geq 1\}$ with at most nlog(n) transitions in 1 tape

Tags: turing-machines, asymptotics

I'm having trouble trying to create this machine. I know the answer should go in the way that we always cut in half the number of a's and b's (so the master theorem aplied at $T(n)=T(n/2)+O(n)$ gives us the requiered asymptotic order). But I don't know how to end the algorithm. My machine does this:

We start with #aaaaabbbbb# and the pointer on the first a, then we replace the first letter of each pair with -, then, after 2n steps we have #-a-a--b-b-# and the pointer is at the end #, then, we go the other way cleaning the first letter of each pair, so after n steps to the left we have #-a----b---#.
And we can check if the position of the last a in aaaaa is the same of the last b in bbbbb (in the example they are both the 2dn letter and this would show that they had the same number of odd numbers)
Thats the idea, but I have the following problems:

1)I don't know when to start checking the position of the last a and b.

2)If I don't have any a or b in the last run, the last iteration would become harder.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

By the way, I'm trying to code it in https://turingmachinesimulator.com/
The code I've made is this one:

```
name: a^nb^n
init: q0
accept: qAccept

q0,a
q1,-,>

q1,a
q0,a,>

q0,b
q2,b,-

q1,b
q2,b,-

q2,b
q3,-,>

q2,_
q4,_,<

q3,b
q2,b,>

q3,_
q4,_,<

q4,b
q5,-,<

q5,b
q4,b,<

q4,a
q6,a,-

q5,a
q6,a,-

q6,a
q7,-,<

q7,a
q6,a,<

q0,-
q0,-,>

q1,-
q1,-,>

q2,-
q2,-,>

q3,-
q3,-,>

q4,-
q4,-,<

q5,-
q5,-,<

q6,-
q6,-,<

q7,-
q7,-,<
```

Comment: This sounds overcomplicated. Just go through the input from left to right, verifying it consists of a bunch of a's followed by a bunch of b's, and at the same time use a standard binary counter to count the number of a's and b's on an auxiliary tape. Since the counter has log n bits, this algorithm works obviously in time $O(n\log n)$. Less obviously, it actually works in time $O(n)$, as the amortized complexity of successive increments is only $O(1)$.

Comment: If you use 2 tapes, the order of the one tape equivalent would be $O(n^2)$, that the reason why I'm trying to divide the number of a's and b's in each run. Changing the title to be more specific.